# DataProtectionConfigurationProvider not working on my Azure app service

Tags: c#, azure, encryption, azure-web-app-service, app-config

I am trying to encrypt my connection string data in my App.config files of my project.
I found [this topic](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/598863/EncryptionplusDecryptionplusConnectionplusStringpl), the solution is basically, I give my connection string -> it encrypts it -> I put the given encrypted string into my App.config and bam. It works (normally).

This is what the encrypted string looks like:

```
<connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="DataProtectionConfigurationProvider">
    <EncryptedData> 
        <CipherData> 
            <CipherValue>AQAAANCMnd...</CipherValue> 
        </CipherData> 
    </EncryptedData> 
</connectionStrings>
```

The solution works on my local solution, I have access to my DB without any problem.
However, when I upload the project to my Azure app service, the database isn't reached. I'm sure it's because of the encrypted data but I don't know why (the db connection works without the encryption).

So if you have an idea, you are my only hope. I would like to keep the encryption simple, I found a lot of other solutions but I find them pretty complicated to make it work.

Thanks by advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [config file encryption method for Azure web site and web job](https://www.fatalerrors.org/a/config-file-encryption-method-for-azure-web-site-and-web-job.html)

> Because of the particularity of the Azure Web AppService platform, so the C# config original encryption method of DataProtectionConfigurationProvider and RSAProtectedConfigurationProvider in the Azure platform is not available.

After reading the article carefully, you can know that DataProtectionConfigurationProvider cannot take effect in the traditional way of Azure web app. You can refer to the solution in the article for processing.